# Max out Number Selector

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to make a `max` option on this function, but unsure whether to do it with `data` attributes on the input but I'm thinking there must be an easier way in jQuery? There can be multiple inputs on one page.

```
     <button type="button" id="sub" class="sub">-</button>
     <input name="updates[{{ variant.id }}]" id="quantity-{{ forloop.index0 }}" onfocus="this.select()" class="quantity field multiple_add" min="0" type="number" value="0" tabindex="1" max="{{ variant.inventory_quantity }}" />
     <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>


 jQuery(function($) {
    $('.add').click(function () {
      $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
    });
    $('.sub').click(function () {
        if ($(this).next().val() > 0) $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Where is the max value coming from?

Comment: It's within the input, but the +/- buttons control the number field

Comment: so read the max attribute? What is the real issue here? Read the input, if value is not greater than the max, then set the new value.

Comment: Don't you just need to do exactly what you're doing with the subtract (inverted, so `.val() < max`), but read the max value from the input attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use data attributes to use one method for both. Read the min and max attributes and see if you are outside the range and set it so it does not go outside it.

```js
$(".inc").on("click", function() {
  // reference the button clicked
  var elem = $(this)
  // get if we are increaing or decreasing the value
  var dir = +elem.data('dir')
  // reference the input attached to the button
  var tb = $(elem.data('input'))
  // get the step, min and max attributes
  var step = +tb.attr("step")
  var min = +tb.attr("min")
  var max = +tb.attr("max")
  // update the value
  var updatedValue = +tb.val() + (dir * step)
  // determine if we are outisde the range, if we are than fix it
  if (updatedValue > max) updatedValue = max
  else if (updatedValue < min) updatedValue = min
  // update the value
  tb.val(updatedValue);  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="inc" type="button" data-dir="-1" data-input="#x1">-</button>
<input type="number" min="0" max="5" step="1" value="3" id="x1"/>
<button class="inc" type="button"  data-dir="1" data-input="#x1">+</button>

<hr/>

<button class="inc" type="button" data-dir="-1" data-input="#x2">-</button>
<input type="number" min="1" max="4" step=".5" value="2" id="x2"/>
<button class="inc" type="button"  data-dir="1" data-input="#x2">+</button>
```

With your comment, without the ids...

```js
$(".inc").on("click", function() {
  // reference the button clicked
  var elem = $(this)
  // get if we are increaing or decreasing the value
  var dir = +elem.data('dir')
  // reference the input attached to the button
  // -1 is before, 1 is after so use next() or prev()
  var tb = elem[dir===-1 ? 'next' : 'prev']()
  // get the step, min and max attributes
  var step = +tb.attr("step")
  var min = +tb.attr("min")
  var max = +tb.attr("max")
  // update the value
  var updatedValue = +tb.val() + (dir * step)
  // determine if we are outisde the range, if we are than fix it
  if (updatedValue > max) updatedValue = max
  else if (updatedValue < min) updatedValue = min
  // update the value
  tb.val(updatedValue);  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="inc" type="button" data-dir="-1">-</button>
<input type="number" min="0" max="5" step="1" value="3"/>
<button class="inc" type="button"  data-dir="1">+</button>

<hr/>

<button class="inc" type="button" data-dir="-1">-</button>
<input type="number" min="1" max="4" step=".5" value="2"/>
<button class="inc" type="button"  data-dir="1">+</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there an easier way by just adding a `data-max` property to each `+` button and have an if statement which checks? As we could have up to 25 buttons automatically generated we may have issues assigning unique id's

Comment: Weird you can not generate a unique id.... can you do it? sure, next and prev like you did.

Answer (score -3):

You could use the `number` input type and set the minimum and maximum that way:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="10">
```

Comment: As this is done with Buttons and incremented programatically the numbers can go above the max

Comment: Not sure what you mean by numbers "can go above the max"? Isn't that the point of a maximum?

Comment: i.e if I set the field to be `max="5"` the javascript ignores it and increments the number anyway

Comment: OK, sure but that would still be an issue with your method? Unless the question you're asking is how to implement validation client side that the number entered is within the min/max bounds?

Comment: If that is the case i.e. "I want to make sure no one enters a number higher than max on the client side" then the answer to your question is you can't make that guarantee anyone can edit the HTML of the page and change the max value or enter a value above the max. 

You would want to use server side validation to check this value on submission.

Comment: @redreddington You can set the value with JavaScript and it can be outside the min and max. That is the problem. OP already has the max attribute set. So when the user clicks the buttons, the code in the OPs example will go past the bounds. That is the issue.